# Approximation by simple functions: a confusion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am confused about the following matter (I come to a conclusion which is obviously wrong)

1. if every real-valued function is a pointwise limit of a sequence of simple functions, e.g.
   \begin{equation*}
   f_n(x) = \left\{ \frac{j}{2^n} : j\in \mathbb{N}\cap [0,2^{2n}] \text {  and  } \frac{j}{2^n} \leq f(x) \right\}
   \end{equation*}
2. and if simple functions are Lebesgue-measurable
3. and if pointwise limit of Lebesgue-measurable functions is again Lebesgue-measurable

then does that mean that every real-valued function is Lebesgue-measurable?

Comment: In what sense can every real-valued function be approximated in your first point? SPecifically, I do not see how $f_n(x)$ is defined and a simple function

Comment: pointwise convergence: edit added

Comment: What is your definition of simple function and is $f_n$ simple? (I still don't see how $f_n(x)$ is defined - as it stands, it seems that $f_n(x)$ is a set, not a number)

Comment: I call a function $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ simple iff the image $f(\Omega)$ is finite.

Comment: I suggest you use a better title.

Comment: Can you suggest a better one? I am new to stackexchange, still learning

Comment: @CebişMellim Ah, there you go. In this context, I would demand that simple functions are also constant on enough intervals to cover $\Omega$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen ??? That's clear from finiteness of $f(\Omega)$. (Except of course the sets where $f$ is constant are not in general _intervals_...)

Comment: The answer is very simple: A simple function need not be measurable. (In books on reals measurability is sometimes part of the defiinition of "simple function"...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement is wrong. Consider the characteristic function of a set which is not Lebesgue measurable. The construction of a non-measurable set is classical.  For instance, see https://www.math.purdue.edu/~zhang24/NonMeasurableSet.pdf